# Probability in comparing two sets of numbers

Tags: probability

Having two sets of numbers: A={0,1,..., 9} and B ={0,3,7} what is the probability in random sampling that the number in B is always higher than A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all the following pairs in the sample:
$(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(0,7),(1,7),(2,7),(3,7),(4,7),(5,7),(6,7)$. 
So there are 10 possibilities out of a total of $10*3=30$.

Comment: Thanks! And can you tell a formula maybe?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by formula here. You can't have formula for specific situations in specific problems.

Comment: I meant some mathematical expression that describe this. Maybe from combinatorics? Imagine that in B you have 100 numbers and in A 1000; you surely won't count every pair by hand...

Comment: Yes, but because these 1100 numbers could be anything, it is hard to find any 'formula'.